# How to create nested folders in iCloud Documents?

Tags: macos, icloud, pages, iwork

I can’t create more than one level of folders in iCloud Documents from iWork. I really want to move my Documents folder (which is all iWork documents) to the cloud. It’s neatly arranged in folders on my disk, but I can’t just drag the folder to cloudify it. Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: how i wish that pages on ipad would allow to sync on dropbox or google drive.. have a hard time in arranging docs with no nested forlders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not. iCloud is designed for iOS devices without a user accessible file system. iCloud files are strictly associated with apps and only allow one level of folder nesting.

If you're not happy with this, you can send feedback to Apple about it here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/icloud.html

You could use Dropbox instead (https://www.dropbox.com/) which has more flexibility around file organisation. The downside is that you only get 2GB free but you can earn more free storage in various ways. Google Drive (https://drive.google.com/start#home) gives you 5GB free.

Comment: I am already using both of them. I have already given feedback about it. I was wondering if it was possible because on the Developer Builds, it gave you API to create folders.

Answer (score 0):

You activate one of the iWorks applications, choose Open from the File menu, choose iCloud in the upper left of the dialog box. In here, you can drag and drop documents on each other just like you do on the iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent and thanks for your input. Please reread the question again, the OP is asking for ways to put *folders* into iCloud, not documents.

Answer (score 0):

I use a tag based filing system, so that I can group files from different applications into subjects.

The tags all have subject names and colours are only used to show them up.